# Ошибка createContext failed: EGL_SUCCESS при запуске приложения под Android 4.2.2

Tags: android

Привет. 
При отладке приложения на планшете возникает ошибка, прерывающая работу приложения:

```
06-14 11:12:11.699 8073-8101/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 332
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: EGL_SUCCESS
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1197)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.throwEglException(GLSurfaceView.java:1188)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1038)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1405)
                                                     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1244)
06-14 11:12:18.039 8136-8167/? E/fb4a(:<default>):MmsConfig: MmsConfig.loadMmsSettings mms_config.xml missing uaProfUrl setting
```

Погуглив, я обнаружил, что данная ошибка имеет отношение к OpenGL ES 2. Соответствующая настройка имеется в манифесте:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

Подробности:
- В приложении используется ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android версии 100.0.0
- ошибка возникает при размещении в активити элемента MapView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.at.agromap.MainActivity">

    <com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

- Используемый планшет ASUS fonepad 7
- Android 4.2.2 API level 17

Никак не могу понять, какова причина происходящей ошибки. Если кто-то сталкивался, было бы интересно узнать, где именно и почему происходит данное исключение?

ПОЗДНЕЕ ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ

Ответ, полученный на форуме разработчиков ArcGis:

> This is a known issue for this release that has not found its way into
>   the release notes yet, we will update the release notes soon. The
>   issue is that some devices do not correctly report their OpenGL
>   configurations to allow us to create our OpenGL context. We need to be
>   specific in creating the OpenGL context to allow many of our map
>   rendering features to work properly (particularly for things like
>   Vector Tiled Layers). We have implemented a solution which works on
>   most devices, but it will still be problematic on some, especially
>   older devices running older versions of Android. Please try on another
>   device or the emulator.

Получается, что нужно либо ждать следующего релиза SDK, либо использовать более новое устройство (возможно Android 5 или выше)

Answer (score 0):

Каков код приложения? Используется рисование, графический движок или т.п.? Какой планшет и версия андроида? Ошибка или\и специфичная для некоторых девайсов, или для уровня апи. Смотрите

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6186

Comment: Спасибо, пока обнаружил, что ошибка появляется только в случае использования элемента карты из ArcGis SDK. Причем происходит ошибка где-то "в недрах" SDK. Поскольку кит закрытый, нет возможности изучить его исходники.